# Subclipse connection error during branch reintegration

Tags: java, svn, branch, subclipse, reintegration

My situation is this: I work on a java project in eclipse and use Subclipse for source control. Recently, work on a branch was completed and reintegration was attempted. However, my  (shitty mobile) broadband connection decided to bug out about 75% through the merge to trunk. Now, whenever I retry the same merge I get the error 
"Filesystem has no item
svn: '/forge/!svn/bc/15895/trunk/branches/AbilityWork' path not found".

Since the actual reintegration was not done, is there some way to work around this and get a chance to complete the reintegration or perhaps some roundabout way to "rescue" the changes in the branch since they were quite involved.

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance!

Answer (score 1):

If you say "merge" it means an operation on your working copy. So you could [**revert**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re25.html) your working copy(all changes are undone) and start over with your merge again.

You need to commit your merge to "finalize" the result in your subversion repository. 
As Subversion is transaction based, it is not possible to commit half of a merge. then nothing would be commited(transaction rollback).

Comment: I did revert my working copy, but the error is still present wether I try to merge trunk changes into the branch or vice-versa.

Comment: this is plaguing me intermittently as well, but only since I moved to latest Eclipse version (Kepler) with the subclipse plugin.  checking out a new working copy is not a resolution for this issue.

Comment: can you perform the merge on commandline or any other svn client?